# Finding the matrix representation of a certain function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, vectors

So I need to find the matrix representation of the function f.

f = [.]<sub>β</sub> given by [$\vec v$]<sub>β</sub> = $\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\end{pmatrix}$ where $\vec v = a_1\vec v_1 + a_2\vec v_2 + a_3\vec v_3 + a_4\vec v_4$.

The basis β = {$\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$} = {$\vec v_1, \vec v_2, \vec v_3, \vec v_4$}.

The problem is that I don't know what f = [.]<sub>β</sub> means. I was told that its the function that takes as input a vector $\vec v$, and outputs the column vector $a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4$ otherwise known as the "coordinates with respect to the basis beta" function but I'm still not sure what I need to do.

Comment: Well firstly, you need some prescription for the function $f$.

Comment: Then you can look at my answers to these questions to try to understand what matrix representation of a function means: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283988/what-are-the-building-blocks-of-a-vector/1284005), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992188/how-to-find-the-matrix-representation-of-a-linear-tranformation/1992195), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564507/how-do-i-find-the-matrix-with-respect-to-a-different-basis/1564625), [4](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460141/on-the-change-of-coordinates-of-a-matrix).

Comment: I do know what the matrix representation of a function is, I just don't know how to find the specific function.

Comment: That conflicts with the first sentence of your question.  But OK.  You still need some prescription for $f$ -- or its action on a basis or *something* tangible about it.  Is it supposed to be the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to $\beta$?

Comment: It is a change of basis matrix from the standard basis to β. I know how to find the change of basis but what I have no idea how to do is with that dot. All it says is that f is some dot with respect to the basis but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: The notation $[\cdot]_\beta$ means a matrix with stuff inside (rows of numbers in this case) wrt the basis $\beta$.  That's all the dot means: "stuff goes here".

Comment: He also said something about how it can also be written as f(b) = [v] with the subscript beta. He also said that the function takes the input of v and outputs the column vector a1 a2 a3 a4. So if that's the case then would f just be the v function that I listed above? Then would that make [f] just an identity matrix? That last paragraph in the question is how the problem was described to me and I don't really know what that description means.

Comment: Without knowing more about what $\vec v$ is, this is a ambiguous question.  My guess would be that $\vec v$ is supposed to be a vector in $\Bbb R^4$ and $f$ is the change of basis function from the vector $\vec v$ to its representation wrt the basis $\beta$, $[\vec v]_\beta$.  In that case, yes: $f$ is an identity function, but its matrix representation won't be the identity matrix $I = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & \cdots \\ 0 & 1 & \cdots \\ \vdots & \vdots &\ddots}$ -- it'll be the change of basis matrix $[I]_{\beta \leftarrow \mathcal{E}}$ where $\mathcal E$ is the standard basis.

Comment: I said that $\vec v = a_1\vec v_1 + a_2\vec v_2 + a_3\vec v_3 + a_4\vec v_4$ and that each $\vec v_1, \vec v_2$ ect is a column in the basis vector. So $\vec v_1$ would be the first column in the basis vector and so on.

Comment: OK, then $\vec v$ *is* some vector in $\Bbb R^4$ so everything starting from "$f$ is the change of basis function" in my previous comment is true.  Find the change of basis matrix.